# how to debug why GDB bell on pressing b?

Tags: macos, gdb

**problem:**

GDB makes the bell sound when pressing b (only lowercase) at making unable to use commands with b (e.g. break -> reak)

**tried:**

- gbd --nx = same problem
- nothing on google, stackoverflow
- works ok in other programs in terminal

**system:**

- OSX 10.6.6
- GDB 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1510)
- iTerm 0.20.20110109 or Terminal 2.1.1 (273)

**solution:**

thanks to Matt Curtis hint, the problem was in `~/.inputrc` which had only a `story-search-backward` - removing the file (old tests that went wrong) and I have my b back ;)

Comment: @close-voters: this is a GDB question. You really think that's a power user tool?

Comment: Where is your gdb running, on your local machine or somewhere over ssh/telnet/etc.?

Comment: Do you have a stuck key? Is there anything in your `~/.inputrc`? Do any other programs have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out your `~/.inputrc` - maybe <kbd>C-b</kbd> is bound to something?